# Cериализация данных C++

Tags: c++

код сервера

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *port;
  int port_atoi;
  char s1[] = "-p";
  int k = strcmp(s1, argv[1]);
  if (k == 0 && argc==3)
  {
    port = argv[2];
    port_atoi = atoi(port);
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "Usage : server -p [port]" << endl;
    return 1;
  }
  int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  struct sockaddr_in addr;
  addr.sin_port = htons(port_atoi);
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.0.60", &(addr.sin_addr));

  if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
  {
    cout << "error : bind" << endl;
    exit(2);
  }

  int listener = listen(sockfd, 1);
  if(listener < 0)
  {
    cout<<"error : listen "<<endl;
    exit(3);
  }
  int incoming;
  int sock;
  char buf[1024];
  char hello[] = "hello client";

  while(1)
  {
    sock = accept(sockfd, NULL, NULL);
    if(sock)
    {cout<<"connection"<<endl;}
    recv(sock, buf , sizeof(buf), 0 );
    send(sock, hello, sizeof(hello), 0);
    cout << buf << endl;
    close(sock);
  }


  return 0;
}
```

код клиента

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
using namespace std;

struct Client
{   
    int key;
    const char *value; 
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Client kli;
    kli.key = 1;
    kli.value = "Hard_Disk";

    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(3000);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.0.60", &(addr.sin_addr));
    if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)& addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        cout << "error : connection" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    char buf[1024];
    char hello[] = "hello server";
    send(sockfd, hello, sizeof(hello), 0);
    recv(sockfd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
    close(sockfd);

    cout<<buf<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Как в такой ситуации лучше всего передать структуру? Нашел,что можно решить вопрос с помощью boost.asio,json,xml, но по докам так и не дошло как это делать.Больше интересует самый простой способ,чтобы понять суть т.к сам новичок.

Comment: *Какую* конкретно структуру?

Comment: в коде клиента перед int main()

Comment: Пересылать отдельно значение `key`, длину строки, саму строку. При чтении читать key, длину строки, готовить буфер нужного размера, читать строку...

Comment: То есть переслать key, принять его, переписать код , переслать строку ,принять её? Если перевести целиком структуру в байты на клиенте,а на севере из байтов в объект, такое возможно?

Comment: Конечно невозможно. Вы уверены, что по адресу, где у вас на клиенте лежит строка, на сервере будет лежать такая же строка?...  Вашим способом вы записываете не содержимое строки в структуре, а указатель на нее, на какую-то другую память, в которой содержатся интересующая вас информация. Вы же предлагаете писать просто указатель...

Comment: Получается примерно так - жена говорит собраться в отпуск и в машину в багажник сложить, ну, там, матрас надувной, палатку, мангал и шампуры - ну, в общем, барахло. Вы в багажник кладете бумажки с надписями "Матрас - на антресолях", "Палатка - на балконе" и т.д. 

По приезду на место (сервер) читаете - вынимаете из бумажника бумажки с надписями, где что лежит. Но и шкаф теперь совсем другой, и балкон тоже - если вообще есть, так что втык от жены - это примерно и есть результат вот такой пересылки и попытки раскрыть палатку, которой нет...

Comment: Посмотрите вопросы типа https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829528/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb - ведь запись/чтение в файл - по сути та же передача между клиентом и сервером.

Comment: Вот если структура - POD, т.е., скажем, `struct Client
{   
    int key;
    char value[512]; 
};` - ну, тогда дело другое...

Comment: Так, я понял. При передаче с клиента ,на сервере я получаю иероглифы, а с переменой int все в порядке. Но если я делаю struct Client { int key; char value[512]; } то в этом случае можно же перевести в байты а на сервере из байт в объект?Я хочу получить целиком объект, и потом записать его в std::map(это не требуется пояснять),чтобы получилась некая база данных.Поэтому волнует передача целиком объекта

Comment: Я же это и написал - если у вас Plain Old Data - так сказать, "все свое ношу с собой" - дело другое. Но это не всегда удобно...

Comment: Можно вместо char* хранить std::string, и передавать размер строки в байтах и сами байты строки. А при приёме читать сначала ваше число, потом размер строки, и потом по полученном размеру считывать нужное количество байт строки.

Comment: Почитал о чтении/записи в файл, и это действительно очень похоже на то как данные передаются в сокетах. Harry, спасибо!