# Как считать длинную строку из файла в переменную std::string с помощью std::fread?

Tags: c++, строки, binary

```cpp
string str;
fread(&str[0], sizeof(char), 25, file);
```

Увы, работает только со строками длинной до 12 символов. Как считать длинную строку именно через `string`.

С `write()` таких проблем не обнаружено.

Comment: Измените название на что-то подобное: "Как считать длинную строку из фала с помощью std::fread?". Поставьте чётко вопрос.

Comment: @monstr s derevni а случайно не кириллический текст читаете?

Answer (score 0):

Судя по тому, что хотя бы читаете не в `&str`, уже понимаете, что так просто не POD читать нельзя. Значит, четверть дела сделано. Судя по тому, что читаете ровно 25 символов - значит, длину тоже знаете. Еще четверть. Еще одна четверть на надежду, что *записано* тоже верно...

Осталась четверть на то, чтоб перед тем как читать - выделить нужную память.

Скажем,

```
string str(25,' ');
```

или

```
string str;
str.resize(25);
```

Ну, и читать формально лучше все же по указателю, который возвращает `.data()`

```
fread(str.data(), sizeof(char), 25, file);
```

Но очень рекомендую почитать все же, например, [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/829528/195342).

Comment: `.data()` возвращает `const char *` до C++17.

Comment: В случае с `str.resize(20);` мы обязательно должны вводить строку фиксированного размера и получить ее с таким же размером. Иначе мы получаем нужную строку с мусором в конце.
Тогда как в первом случае строка могла быть размером ДО 12 символов (динамическую) и получить мы могли такую же динамическую строку.

Comment: @monstrsderevni Я исхожу из того, что ТС адекватен и знает, что делает, читая именно 25 символов...

Answer (score 0):

### В чем проблема?

[`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) и `std::vector`, при инициализации, выделяют память под некоторое количество элементов, чтобы не запрашивать память из кучи на каждое добавление. Другими словами, строка имеет вид:

```cpp
class string {
    char * _buffer;
    size_t _size;
    size_t _capacity;
}
```

где, `_size` - сколько элементов из буфера заняты (размер строки),
`_capacity` - размер буфера `_buffer`.

> 1. Default constructor. Constructs empty string (**zero size** and **unspecified capacity**). If no allocator is supplied, allocator is obtained from a default-constructed instance.

При создании строки `string str;` у неё есть буфер некоторого размера, даже если его явно не указывать. Именно поэтому заполнение буфера такой строки будет работать пока мы не превысим его размеров.

Ещё один подвох ожидает нас в связи с тем, что при использования буфера строки `string str;` мы не меняем `_size` и при попытке доступа к данным, через методы класса, мы всё равно получим пустую строку.

### Как решить?

Создать экземпляр класса `std::string` с нужным размером буфера. Можно воспользоваться:

- [конструктором](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) под номером 2:

  > 2. Constructs the string with **count** copies of character **ch**.
- методом [`.resize()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize). Замечу что [`.reserve()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve), не смотря на то, что меняет `_buffer` и `_capacity`, не меняет `_size`.

  > 1. Informs a std::basic_string object of **a planned change in size**, so that it *can manage the storage allocation appropriately*.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    const size_t LEN = 11;
    std::string str(LEN, '\0');

    std::FILE * in = std::fopen("data.bin", "r");
    std::fread(&str[0], sizeof(char), LEN, in);
    std::fclose(in);

    std::cout << "Data: " << str << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @monstrsderevni это не форум. Один вопрос - один ответ. Вопрос можно поправить, если есть что дополнить.