# Проблема в строках класса, которые я передаю через сокет

Tags: c++

```
class JoinPlayerPacket {
public:
    PacketType type;
    const char* playerId; // превращается в непонятные символы после передачи через сокет
};

// SERVER

JoinPlayerPacket packet;
packet.playerId = "maxrskiy";
send(sock, (char*)packet, sizeof(packet), 0);

// CLIENT

LeavePlayerPacket buf;
int bytesReceived = recv(sock, (char*)&buf, 4096, 0);
cout << buf.playerId << endl; // отображает искаженные символы
```

У меня возникла проблема, когда я пытался передать класс, в котором есть переменная со строкой по сокету, строка, на стороне которой я передаю класс, была деформирована, то есть превратилась в непонятные символы. Как этого избежать? Я использую TCP-сокет. Можно пример кода как правильно передавать объекты классов по TCP сокету?

Comment: Это переменная не со строкой, а с указателем на начало буфера со строкой, который лежит где-то.

Comment: Подскажи тогда, пожалуйста, как мне правильно передать объект класса по сокету?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/555710/%d0%a1%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%a1

Comment: Можно-ли это как-то провернуть без сериализации?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/829528/195342 - та же проблема: запись в файл или передача по сети по сути ничем не отличаются. По сути, меняйте `write` на `send` :)

Comment: Не понял про write??

Comment: Нет, без сериализации никак не обойтись.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1281308/%d0%94%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80-%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0/1281352#1281352