# Запись в бинарный файл объектов класса, содержащие вектор

Tags: c++, классы, vector, fstream, binary-file

У меня класс заказа с вектором товаров, номером, строками и т.д.. Как я могу осуществить запись и чтение вектора заказов в бинарный файл? Ведь размер каждого объекта будет разный из-за вектора внутри. И если я могу изначально записывать размер вектора и благодаря этому узнать куда переместить указатель в файле. Но как мне быть с string?

Comment: Или читать последовательно, или подготовить и записать индексную таблицу в начале или конце файла — как удобнее, в которой просто указаны смещения в файле записанных элементов вектора. Главное — не забывайте о специфике [записи/чтения не-POD в файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/829528/195342).

Comment: А чем, собственно, string отличается от вектора символов? Ну, еще можно вывести string, заключив ее символы в кавычки (но в этом случае надо правильно заэскейпить возможные кавычки внутри нее)

Comment: `write f size ; write f str .. mems = read f ; tmp = new char[ mems + 1 ]; read f tmp ; str = tmp ; delete tmp ;` и про последнюю `'\00'` не забыть